# Animating a child object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have this table drawer I am trying to animate, where if the player presses "E", the drawer opens and stays open. And when the player presses "E" again, the door closes. 
The script is based on the player entering a trigger and I have it on multiple doors in my scene.
 I'm running into a few issues though, with the drawer when the player presses "E" the collider on the door moves but the drawer gameObject does not. 
I have come to the conclusion that it's not script because its working finds on the doors, but I have tried everything else. I will attach some images for reference.

```
public class DoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject OpenPanel = null;

private bool _isInsideTrigger = false;

public Animator _animator;

public string OpenText = "Press 'E' to open";

public string CloseText = "Press 'E' to close";

private bool _isOpen = false;

private void Start()
{
    OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = true;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(true);
        UpdatePanelText();
    }
}

private void UpdatePanelText()
{
    Text panelText = OpenPanel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    if (panelText != null)
    {
        panelText.text = _isOpen ? CloseText: OpenText;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = false;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private bool IsOpenPanelActive
{
    get
    {
        return OpenPanel.activeInHierarchy;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (IsOpenPanelActive && _isInsideTrigger)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            _isOpen = !_isOpen;

            Invoke("UpdatePanelText", 1.0f);

            _animator.SetBool("open", _isOpen);
        }
    }
}
```

}
//Credit Jayanam Youtube Channel for Script

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds more like the code isnt working.. Add some debug statements, show the result and your code it will be easier to help you

Comment: @BugFinder its not code actually but static batching which is creating problem

Answer (score 1):

> In order to take advantage of static batching, you need to explicitly specify that certain GameObjects are static and do not move, rotate or scale in the game. To do so, mark GameObjects as static using the Static checkbox in the Inspector

[Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html)

You can make the object animate again when you uncheck the static checkbox. Good thing you put the images ahead otherwise this problem would have been difficult to resolve.

---

Note: You can disable the static batching on entire Table or you can disable static batching on the child i.e. the Drawer. Disabling the static batching on child would be more beneficial I believe but if some problem in animation comes then might as well try disabling static batching on entire object and see if it suits your need.

Comment: So I actually just did that, because the word static was showing under the table but now the drawer animation starts on entry, even though I have OpenPanel.SetActive(false); after the start

Comment: Now that your animation issue is resolved I believe next thing you can start is checking if OnColliderEnter/OnColliderStay is getting called and making the Drawer open. Someone must be calling it in your script. Do check your code.

Comment: I just added the code, and if you look you will notice that the triggers are dependent on the player tag interaction so I'm not sure what might be calling the drawer to open.

Comment: You said you are making "OpenPanel.SetActive(false);" in the start yet you are enabling it in the OnTriggerEnter. You should either remove the enable panel from ontrigger enter or rework on your animation script to be in non used state rather than setting disable/enable state. As from what I can see your code is actually having text component attached to table because of which you might want to follow the second method i suggested. Maybe it would be better if you rewrite the animation state. And you need to ask this as another question as the orignal question is already answered.